# Recursive StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

I was trying to do a sudoku solver program and I have a problem with StackOverflow Exception. I don't know what I have to do to resolve that problem because the algorithm is good and is working if there are only a few recursive functions.I was trying to resolve the problem with try-catch but I'm not very good at that. Here is the code, how to make it work properly without having that StackOverflow Error

```
public static int Rezolva_sudoku(int i,int j,int[,] cells, int[,] cells2)
    {
        try
        {

            int ok = 0;
            int val;
            if (j == 10)
            {
                j = 1;
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 10)
            {
                for (int m = 1; m <= 9; m++)
                    for (int p = 1; p <= 9; p++)
                        if (cells[m, p] != 0)
                            ok = 1;
                if (ok == 1)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }

            if ((cells[i, j] == cells2[i, j]) && back == 0)
                if (j == 1)
                    return Rezolva_sudoku(i - 1, 9, cells, cells2);
                else
                    return Rezolva_sudoku(i, j - 1, cells, cells2);
            if (i != 10)
            {
                back = 1;
                if (cells[i, j] == cells2[i, j] && back == 1)
                    return Rezolva_sudoku(i, j + 1, cells, cells2);
                for (val = cells[i, j] + 1; val <= 9; val++)
                {
                    if (legal(i, j, val, cells))
                    {

                        cells[i, j] = val;
                        return Rezolva_sudoku(i, j + 1, cells, cells2);

                    }


                }
            }
            if (i != 10)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    back = 0;
                    cells[i, j] = 0;
                    return Rezolva_sudoku(i - 1, 9, cells, cells2);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cells[i, j - 1] == cells2[i, j - 1])
                    {
                        if (j == 2)
                        {
                            if (cells[i - 1, 9] == cells2[i - 1, 9])
                            {
                                back = 0;
                                cells[i, j] = 0;
                                return Rezolva_sudoku(i - 1, 8, cells, cells2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                back = 0;
                                cells[i, j] = 0;
                                return Rezolva_sudoku(i - 1, 9, cells, cells2);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            back = 0;
                            cells[i, j] = 0;
                            return Rezolva_sudoku(i, j - 2, cells, cells2);
                        }
                    }
                    back = 0;
                    cells[i, j] = 0;
                    return Rezolva_sudoku(i, j - 1, cells, cells2);

                }


            }

        }
        catch (StackOverflowException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried increasing java's allocated memory? If your code is working on small suduko puzzles but not large ones then the problem is just that the recursive algorithm needs to use a lot of memory and java is running out.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, that's why I didn't tried it. Can you tell me how to do that? And this is made in Visual Studio C#

Comment: Oh you are using c#, well go google "how to increase visual studio c# allocated memory"

Comment: Is there other solution or only that?

Comment: other solution would be dont use recursion or you need to find a more efficient recursive algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: The code you posted does very little in execution: it defines a long function and quits without actually running the code.  There is no documentation on your approach, no debugging `print` statements to follow the data and control flow, no examples ...

Comment: Overall, I expect that the problem is some flaw in your logic that drives the call stack to a large or infinite depth.  There shouldn't be a need to go more than **N** levels deep, where **N** is the number of blank cells in the original grid.

Comment: Sorry for not describing my problem properly. I don't think that it's a problem in my logic(or maybe I can't see it) but if I give too much numbers at the beginning and the program needs to do a lot of recursive functions then it return a text like this(An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in sudoku_bun2.exe) and if i don't give any number at beginning it works properly, or if i give only a few numbers the program is working properly too. So I think I need to increase my visual studio c# allocated memory but I don't know how to do this yet

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're running out of stack space.

Every time a function is called, some data gets put on the stack, and it gets taken off again when the function ends.

When a function calls itself recursively, more data gets put on the stack for every time it calls itself, over and over, and none of them get taken off the stack until one of them ends.

Your problem is that this can quickly fill up the stack, and when you run out of stack space, the program will crash. Recursive functions are great for some things, but only if they don't need to recur too many times.

Now there's good news and bad news: the good news is this can be fixed, but the bad news is the best way to fix it is to completely rewrite your program so it does its work using loops instead of using a recursive function.